# Android get data from gmail, attachment is json

Tags: android, json, android-intent, gmail, attachment

**What I want:** Get data from json in gmail attachment.

**Description:** Open Gmail, click attachment which is json file. Json file handle data which I need to procesing.

In Manifest I declarated

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/json"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Next i use

```
Intent intent = getIntent();        
if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)){ 
intent.getData <- I suppose from here i can get my infomation
        }
```

But intent.getData only return Uri, and I read someone i must use ContentResolver, InputStream and something else to for example write my data from json to string. If some can explain how it works on example I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i have it

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Uri data = intent.getData();
//            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
            String text = getStringFromShare(data);
            Log.d("sasas", "onCreate: sometext");
        }
    }

    private String getStringFromShare(Uri data) {
        String text = null;
        try {

            ContentResolver cr = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
            InputStream is = cr.openInputStream(data);
            if (is != null) {

                StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String str;
                if (is != null) {
                    while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        buf.append(str);
                    }
                }
                is.close();
                text = buf.toString();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return text;
    }
```